# GridBagLayout and Resizing

Tags: java, swing, resize, gridbaglayout

getting a bit confused with GridBagLayout.

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MihatteFrame extends JFrame {

 private JTextArea area;
 private JTextField textField;
 private Button b;
 final static boolean shouldFill = true;

public MihatteFrame() {

    setTitle("見張ってしながら...");
    setSize(500,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    if (shouldFill) {
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    }

    area = new JTextArea(5, 15);
    area.setEditable(false);
    area.setCursor(null);
    area.setOpaque(false);
    area.setFocusable(false);
    area.setLineWrap(true);
    area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    this.add(area, c);

    textField = new JTextField(20);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    this.add(textField);
    //textField.addActionListener(this);

    b = new Button("Proceed");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(b);

    setVisible(true);   
}

public void displayText(String text) {
    area.setText(text);
    //textField.setText(text)
    }

}
```

I understand the basics and its working well, it`s sorting out the resizing (specifically downsizing) issue.

When the text areas weight is 0 and the text fields weight is 1, there is no problem with resizing, but the text area is in the centre and not right up against the left-hand side, despite the anchoring.

When the text areas weight is anything above 0 and the text fields weight correlates (eg. 0.2/0.8), everything looks snug as a bug, and upsizing is fine, but downsizing, the text field is reduced to 1 character wide.

I dont mind the text area resizing with the frame, but I want it to return to its original size when the frame is made smaller, not shove the textfield against the proceed button.

I have read that I may need to put this in a JPanel border layout - am not sure what this would look like in code, so if anyone could tell me what goes where if that is the case, would be grateful.

So questions:

1. Is there a way to make the text area stay anchored to the West AND
   not have the textfield reduced to a small size when resized?
2. Why are my anchors not working?
3. Do I need to put the text area in a JPanel with relation to another layout, and if so, where does the code go?
4. Why does everyone fear GridBagLayout? The amount of "I avoid this at all costs" I`ve seen...

Thank you!
(Ps. am halfway through implementing actionlistener, so if it looks half-complete, that`s why).

Comment: use different GridBagConstraints object for all the components. This should work.

Comment: You're modifying the constraints, but when adding the components, you don't pass the constraints as argument. `this.add(textField)` should be `this.add(textField, c)`.

Comment: Adding to what JBNizet said, you are also adding `JTextField` and `JButton` at the same position, i.e. `Row 0` and `Column 2`, if ever you will imply to the said line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ipadx for the `JTextField`. I would suggest also to place the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`.

You use c.gridx = 2 twice for the `JTextField` and `JButton`.

It's better to post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to let us check what's wrong.